# If we connect VSTS to our Azure AD, is it a requirement that all users exist in AD?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-devops

If we connect our VSTS to our Azure AD, is it a requirement that all users exist in AD?

Comment: The information on the [VSTS Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/access-with-azure-ad) is pretty detailed. Maybe you're also interested in [this article](https://www.tshooter.com.br/en/2016/04/19/authenticating-users-foreign-in-vsts/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user is required existing in current AD (can add guest user to AD).